# Data visualization with Azure Web App filtering

Tags: azure, iot, azure-web-app-service

I'm following the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-live-data-visualization-in-web-apps) to visualize data from IoT hub. In my use case, I have multiple devices sending data to the IoT hub. I'd like to know if it's possible to use single web app to visualize data from a specific device, which parameter is sent through HTTP GET method. The current workaround simply ignores data from other devices, which is not ideal. I wonder if there is a right way to do this.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, as a consumer side, we can leverage `deviceId` parameter to filter the data from the specific device.

As the demo [Create a simulated device app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-node-node-getstarted#create-a-simulated-device-app) we can send the data from device with particular `deviceId` to IOT hub, then we can create a new rule in the demo used in your post, https://github.com/Azure-Samples/web-apps-node-iot-hub-data-visualization, to get the HTTP get params from the URL, and set as a filter against the `deviceId`.

As the web-apps-node-iot-hub-data-visualization application uses expressjs as a http server, so we can create a route rule to get `deviceId` from url like:

```
app.get('/deviceId/:id', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.params);
  var iotHubReader = new iotHubClient(connectionString, consumerGroup);
  iotHubReader.startReadMessage(function (obj, date) {
    try {

      if (obj.deviceId == req.params.deviceId) {
        console.log(date);
        date = date || Date.now()
        wss.broadcast(JSON.stringify(Object.assign(obj, {
          time: moment.utc(date).format('YYYY:MM:DD[T]hh:mm:ss')
        })));
      }

    } catch (err) {
      console.log(obj);
      console.error(err);
    }
  });
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html');
})
```

And then we can visit the application with deivceId like:
`<hostname>/deviceId/myFirstNodeDevice`

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I wonder `req.params.deviceId` should be  `req.params.id`. Another problem I ran into while working in this change is `res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html');` My browser (chrome) generates error messages `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <` (index.html line 1) I googled around but couldn't find a way to solve this. Any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: per my experience,  it may be the issue that there are something wrong in expressjs route code, you can try to check the similar issue at https://github.com/expressjs/express/issues/2891

Comment: I finally figured it out. The real problem here is the `index.html` is not loaded with correct path. It becomes `hostname/deviceId/index.html`. Hence, all the contents in `index.html` cannot be found.